# How do I get my card grid items to align horizontally?

Tags: html, css, codepen

I've created a codepen for an e-commerce style page https://codepen.io/williamsrashon/pen/JjRXaKy, but the items listed for sale are all stacked vertically as oppose to horizontally. Can anyone help? I commented out the listed-items div for the grids on the css, because it wasn't helping my issue. FYI I've tried removing the duplicate grid css part from the cards div section as well, nothing done under the listed-items div is being responded to, so I put it all under cards' div.

This is some of the HTML:

```
<div class="listed-items">
    <div class = "cards">
      
    <div class ="item-description">
     <p>Men's Guess Watch</p> 
      <p> $165 </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class ="item-pic">
      <img class="itemimg" src ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQRxdr9vUo-rPOZelaFVMPHFtQUI2ZOJn9X_krP_Aa0KTlNr8gB1AWzfW5OqeKpAf5qzH_Mvald&usqp=CAc"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="buy-option">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Vendor: Guess Inc.</a></br>
      <button class ="buy-opt">Buy Now
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"></a>
    </button>
     <div class="rating rating2"><!--
        --><a href="#5" title="Give 5 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#4" title="Give 4 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#3" title="Give 3 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#2" title="Give 2 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#1" title="Give 1 star">★</a>
    </div> </div>

  <br>
       
    <div class ="item-description">
     <p>Mackbook Pro</p> 
      <p> $1249 </p>
    </div>
         
    <div class ="item-pic">
      <img class="itemimg" src ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR0QjsRQfYpJLxrrIgB90H24rzbhA2hGKaIWQ&usqp=CAU"/>
    </div>
         
    <div class="buy-option">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Vendor: Apple Inc.</a></br>
      <button class ="buy-opt">Buy Now
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"></a>
      </button>
     <div class="rating rating2"><!--
        --><a href="#5" title="Give 5 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#4" title="Give 4 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#3" title="Give 3 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#2" title="Give 2 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#1" title="Give 1 star">★</a>
        </div> </div>
     
     <br>
 
    <div class ="item-description">
     <p>Men's Nike Shoe</p> 
      <p> $85 </p>
    </div>
        
    <div class ="item-pic">
      <img class="itemimg" src ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ394wW-WDT5yNqkuCyLE3dKtWE0V7nVhUc0Q&usqp=CAU"/>
    </div>
        
    <div class="buy-option">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Vendor: Nike Inc.</a></br>
      <button class ="buy-opt">Buy Now
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"></a>
      </button>
     <div class="rating rating2"><!--
        --><a href="#5" title="Give 5 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#4" title="Give 4 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#3" title="Give 3 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#2" title="Give 2 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#1" title="Give 1 star">★</a>
        </div> </div>
  <br>
  
  <br>
    
    <div class ="item-description">
     <p>Supreme - Spider Man Shirt</p> 
      <p> $250 </p>
    </div>
         
    <div class ="item-pic">
      <img class="itemimg" src ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT9QXY9MjKfMxGf8J-dMA8B53nC9KkV9296Yg&usqp=CAU"/>
    </div>
         
    <div class="buy-option">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Vendor: Supreme Clothing</a></br>
      <button class ="buy-opt">Buy Now
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"></a>
      </button>
     <div class="rating rating2"><!--
        --><a href="#5" title="Give 5 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#4" title="Give 4 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#3" title="Give 3 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#2" title="Give 2 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#1" title="Give 1 star">★</a>
        </div> </div>
  <br>
    
    <div class ="item-description">
     <p>Vizio Smart Tv 50"</p> 
      <p> $299.99</p>
    </div>
         
    <div class ="item-pic">
      <img class="itemimg" src ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSy4GKybDoYdLUVUTlRK9uQDGeVi7rU4qdO_Q&usqp=CAU"/>
    </div>
         
    <div class="buy-option">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Vendor: Walmart</a></br>
      <button class ="buy-opt">Buy Now
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"></a>
      </button>
     <div class="rating rating2"><!--
        --><a href="#5" title="Give 5 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#4" title="Give 4 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#3" title="Give 3 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#2" title="Give 2 stars">★</a><!--
        --><a href="#1" title="Give 1 star">★</a>
        </div> </div>
```

This is the css:

```
/*.listed-items {
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: repeat (5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat (3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  
} */

.cards { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat (5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat (3, 1fr);
  width: 330px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px whitesmoke;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: From `item-description` to your `<br>` add a containing `<div>` and remove those break tags, then make your `.listed-items` class `display: flex;`. You'll need to add some CSS to get those containing divs the same height and aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: a grid does not work if you declared `display: flex;`. You can also put a grid within a grid (sub-gridding).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've changed some things around, however it still seems to be placing everything on one row. instead of 5 columns, 3 rows as specified. What am I missing?